# Smarty pass argument as function in template

Tags: smarty, anonymous-function

I need to send to the function argument is an anonymous function in a template Smarty. I tried the following code, but it gives an error:

> {$form->block('image', function() { return 'image'; })}

And error:

> on line 14 "{$form->block('image', function() {" unknown function "function"

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (without anonymous function but with additional variable instead).

```
{assign var="image" value="image"}
{$form->block('image', $image )}
```